# how to use gdb debuger with input test file

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, gdb

I am trying to use the gdb debugger on a c++ program that takes a text file on standard input, but I'm unable to figure out how to make the debugger work with my input. I have included my input and executable below so if someone could just show me how to make that work with the debugger I would greatly appreciate it.

```
./bin/bstree_tester - < /home/mydrive/computing/Labs/LabA/inputExample/020.txt
```